# dot product across multiple axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

Given two numpy arrays where the first `d` dimensions are equal in size

```
import numpy

d = 3
a = numpy.random.rand(2, 2, 2, 12, 3)
b = numpy.random.rand(2, 2, 2, 5)
```

I would like to compute the dot-product across those first dimensions. This

```
a2 = a.reshape(-1, *a.shape[d:])
b2 = b.reshape(-1, *b.shape[d:])
out = numpy.dot(numpy.moveaxis(a2, 0, -1), numpy.moveaxis(b2, 0, -2))
```

works, but only if `b` is not of shape `(2, 2, 2)`. Messing around with `reshape` and `moveaxis` also seems more complicated than necessary.

Are there more elegant solutions? (Perhaps with [`tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)?)

Comment: `tensordot` does reshapes and axis moves till it can give the task to `dot`. And then reshapes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that [`tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) *is* helpful after all. This

```
numpy.tensordot(a, b, axes=(range(3), range(3)))
```

does the trick.

Comment: Apparently a better solution, to bad, I'm really fond of `np.einsum`

Comment: Me too, actually. Once you get a hang of the syntax, you can do almost anything. Almost.

Answer (score 2):

Again use [np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```
np.einsum('ijklm,ijkn->lmn',a,b)
```

Comment: I guess this would need adaption for d different from 3, or the number of extra dimensions differing.

Comment: Yes, you have to. `np.einsum` allows ellipsis, but I think the best you can get is something like `np.einsum('ijklm,ijk...->lm...',a,b)`. Especially you can't sum over an unspecified number of axis.

Comment: I suppose at least the lm part can be replaced as well? For ijk, one could construct the string till the alphabet runs out.

Comment: I wasn't able to get rid of the lm part aswell, but maybe there is a way

Comment: As with `tensordot` reshape can reduced the number of axes to a manageable one.  I think the max `ndim` is 32.  You will probably hit memory error first.